# Create a New Record with lookup values

Tags: apex, trigger, lookup

I am trying to create a child (`Appointment__c`)record using after insert trigger.There are lookup values like `Parent_Appointment__c`(lookup on itself),`Account__c` (Lookup to Account),`Parent_Opportunity__c`(Lookup on Opportunity),`Parent_Lost_Business__c`(lookup on Custom object) which are need to be create.Please help with the code where can i fetch lookup values and create record

```
trigger AppointmentOnOpp on Opportunity (after insert) 
{
    Account Acc;
   List<Appointment__c> recordsToCreate = new List<Appointment__c>();
       for(Opportunity Opps:Trigger.New)
       {
        if (Opps.RecordTypeId =='012b0000000M8s5AAC') 
        {
            Appointment__c la = new Appointment__c();
            la.Category__c   ='Monthly Update';
            la.Name ='Monthly Update';
            la.Duration__c ='0.5 hour';
            la.Account__c= [select id,Name from Account where Account__c :=Account].id;
           la.Parent_Appointment__c= ??
           la.Start_Date_Time__c = la.CreatedDate__c;   
            recordsToCreate.add(la);
        }  
       }


insert recordsToCreate; 


}
```

New Trigger

```
trigger CreateEmailTask on Opportunity (after insert, after Update){
 AppointmentOnOpp.createrecord();


 List<Task> taskInsertList = new List<Task>();
 for(Opportunity opp : trigger.new){
  if(opp.Account.Account_Status__c== 'Active' && opp.IsClosed == FALSE && opp.Days_Overdue__c > 10 && opp.Check_on_Status__c == FALSE && opp.RecordTypeId != '012b00000000pLn')
   taskInsertList.add(new Task(OwnerId = opp.OwnerId, WhatId = opp.Id, Subject =''));

  }

   if(taskInsertList.size()>0)

     insert taskInsertList;

}
```

New class

```
public class AppointmentOnOpp {

    public static List<Appointment__c> createrecord()
    {
         List<Appointment__c> recordsToCreate = new List<Appointment__c>();
         for(Opportunity Opps :Trigger.New){
            if (Opps.RecordTypeId =='012b0000000M8s5AAC'){
                Appointment__c la = new Appointment__c();
                la.Category__c   ='Monthly Update';
                la.Name ='Monthly Update';
                la.Duration__c ='0.5 hour';
                la.Account__c= Opps.AccountId;
                la.Parent_Opportunity__c = Opps.Id;
                la.Start_Date_Time__c = la.CreatedDate__c;  
                recordsToCreate.add(la);
            }  
       }
     if(recordsToCreate.size() > 0){
         insert recordsToCreate; 
     }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Please precise your requirement. Where the parent appointment is supposed to come from?

Comment: Reqiurement is whenever Opportuntiy is created automatically Appointment should be created. with specified values. There is a lookup relation  Appointment --> Account and Opportuntiy.  Account__c should come from Opportunity.Accountid, Parent_Opportunity__c should be the opportunity id . Please ignore Parent_Appointment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated trigger code:

```
trigger AppointmentOnOpp on Opportunity (after insert){
    List<Appointment__c> recordsToCreate = new List<Appointment__c>();
        for(Opportunity Opps :Trigger.New){
            if (Opps.RecordTypeId =='012b0000000M8s5AAC'){
                Appointment__c la = new Appointment__c();
                la.Category__c   ='Monthly Update';
                la.Name ='Monthly Update';
                la.Duration__c ='0.5 hour';
                la.Account__c= Opps.AccountId;
                la.Parent_Opportunity__c = Opps.Id;
                la.Start_Date_Time__c = la.CreatedDate__c;  
                recordsToCreate.add(la);
            }  
       }
     if(recordsToCreate.size() > 0){
         insert recordsToCreate; 
     }
}
```

Comment: Due to some issues in other triggers it is not working.So i am including this logic in Apex class and trying to call from different exisitng trigger.It is throwing invalid method name error in trigger. Please find the above new class and New exising trigger

Comment: You need to pass the Trigger.New records to the method createrecord()

Comment: This is how i passed trigger.new  in trigger                       AppointmentOnOpp.createrecord(Trigger.New);

Comment: I got this error now "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: AppointmentOnOpp.createrecord(List<Opportunity>) at line 2 column 2

Comment: Trigger.new needs to be typecasted to List<Opportunity>